# How can I get a specific interface of an Acad object with comtypes (Python)

Tags: python, com, autocad

I am writing a Python3 program to work with AutoCAD.
I use `pyautocad` and `comtypes`.

I can take any object on the drawing and get its best interface.
For example, I can explode some block reference and work with new objects the AutoCAD creates:

```
for NewItem in BlockReference.Explode():
  # NewItem is unusable unknown object here
  NewItem = comtypes.client.GetBestInterface(NewItem)
  # Now NewItem is what it is in Acad (text, line or so on)
  if NewItem.ObjectName == 'AcDbMText':
    ....
```

`GetBestInterface` method is perfect if I want to get 'the best' interface, which supports methods necessary to iterate with it as with a specific Acad object (for example, `AcDbMText`). But if I want, for example, to explode an MText or Dimension, I need methods of `AcDbEntity`.

So, can anyone, please, advice me how can I get not 'the best' but the necessary interface of an object? And, as an ideal, a list of interfaces it supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was only tested with python 2.7:

```
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint
from comtypes.client import GetBestInterface
from comtypes.gen.AutoCAD import IAcadEntity, IAcadObject

# Get acad application
acad = Autocad(create_if_not_exists=True)
# Create a new document
doc1 = GetBestInterface(acad.Application.Documents.Add())
# add a circle in this document and make it visible
circle = GetBestInterface(doc1.ModelSpace.AddCircle(APoint(0.0, 0.0), 1.0))

# to cast to a different interface:
circle = circle.QueryInterface(IDispatch)
circle = circle.QueryInterface(IAcadEntity)
circle = circle.QueryInterface(IAcadObject)
```

Should work, tho. Stay away from [CopyObjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757823/exception-invalid-object-array-with-comtypes). Just sayin'.

Comment: Welcome. You should accept the answer so that others that stumble across your question know the solution works. And because I get points for it ;)