# Exception: Invalid object array with comtypes

Tags: python-2.7, com, autocad, comtypes

I try to implement a simple copy operation between two Autocad documents via COM in Python.

```
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint
from comtypes.client import GetBestInterface
# Get acad application
acad = Autocad(create_if_not_exists=True)
# Create a new document
doc1 = GetBestInterface(acad.Application.Documents.Add())
# add a circle in this document and make it visible
circle = GetBestInterface(doc1.ModelSpace.AddCircle(APoint(0.0, 0.0), 1.0))
doc1.Application.ZoomExtents()
# create another document
doc2 = GetBestInterface(acad.Application.Documents.Add())
# and copy the circle to the new document
doc1.CopyObjects([circle], doc2.ModelSpace)
```

This throws:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copy_bug.py", line 13, in <module>
    doc1.CopyObjects([circle], doc2.ModelSpace)
  File "Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 655, in call_with_inout
    rescode = func(self_, *args, **kw)
_ctypes.COMError: (-2145320837, None, (u'Invalid object array', u'AutoCAD.Application', u'C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\AutoCAD 2015\\HELP\\OLE_ERR.CHM', -2145320837, None))
```

Same thing may be accomplished in VBA with:

```
Dim doc1 As AcadDocument
Set doc1 = ThisDrawing.Application.Documents.add
Dim pt(0 To 2) As Double
pt(0) = 0#: pt(1) = 0#: pt(2) = 0#
Dim circ As AcadCircle
Set circ = doc1.ModelSpace.AddCircle(pt, 1)

ThisDrawing.Application.ZoomExtents

Dim doc2 As AcadDocument
Set doc2 = ThisDrawing.Application.Documents.add

Dim arry(0 To 0) As AcadEntity
Set arry(0) = circ
doc1.CopyObjects arry, doc2.ModelSpace
```

I tried numpy arrays, I tried casting to the `IDispatch` interface, the `IAcadEntity` interface and `IAcadObject` with no success (probably a silly attempt).

```
circle = circle.QueryInterface(IAcadEntity)
```

I also tried to look inside `site-packages\comtypes\automation.py` but that's above my pay grade. Setting the `self.vt` to `VT_ARRAY | VT_DISPATCH` in `_set_value` does no good but I suspect that the problem is along those lines because, if we change `Dim arry(0 To 0) As AcadEntity` to `Dim arry(0 To 0) As Variant` the VBA example will also throw `Invalid object array`.

---

I should mention that I un-commented two lines in `site-packages\comtypes\automation.py`:

```
# These are not yet implemented:
POINTER(IUnknown): VT_UNKNOWN,
POINTER(IDispatch): VT_DISPATCH,
```

So .... help?!

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, there are some ugly hacks like:

```
Dim doc1 As AcadDocument
Set doc1 = ThisDrawing.Application.Documents.add
Dim pt(0 To 2) As Double
pt(0) = 0#: pt(1) = 0#: pt(2) = 0#
Dim circ As AcadCircle
Set circ = doc1.ModelSpace.AddCircle(pt, 1)

ThisDrawing.Application.ZoomExtents
Dim EXTMIN As Variant: EXTMIN = ThisDrawing.GetVariable("EXTMIN")
Dim EXTMAX As Variant: EXTMAX = ThisDrawing.GetVariable("EXTMAX")

Call ThisDrawing.SendCommand( _
    "_SELECT Window " & CStr(EXTMIN(0)) & "," & CStr(EXTMIN(1)) & _
    " " & CStr(EXTMAX(0)) & "," & CStr(EXTMAX(1)) & vbNewLine)
doc1.SendCommand ("_COPYBASE 0,0" & vbNewLine)

Dim doc2 As AcadDocument
Set doc2 = ThisDrawing.Application.Documents.add
doc2.SendCommand ("_PASTECLIP 0,0" & vbNewLine)
```

---

```
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint
from comtypes.client import GetBestInterface

acad = Autocad(create_if_not_exists=True)
doc1 = GetBestInterface(acad.Application.Documents.Add())
circle = GetBestInterface(doc1.ModelSpace.AddCircle(APoint(0.0, 0.0), 1.0))
doc1.Application.ZoomExtents()

EXTMIN = doc1.GetVariable("EXTMIN")
EXTMAX = doc1.GetVariable("EXTMAX")

doc1.SendCommand( "_SELECT Window %f,%f %f,%f\n\r" % (
    EXTMIN[0], EXTMIN[1], EXTMAX[0], EXTMAX[1]))
doc1.SendCommand ("_COPYBASE 0,0\n\r")

doc2 = GetBestInterface(acad.Application.Documents.Add())
doc2.SendCommand ("_PASTECLIP 0,0\n\r")
```

(of course you can create a selection set but you cannot make an selection set active; that would be madness)

Please post a better answer!